# Is there a way to recover MySql user Password?

Tags: mysql

I forgot the password to one of the user in MySQL. Is there a way to recover MySQL user Password?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot **recover** but you can **set a different one** though:

like this:

> - Stop & start the MySQL process with --skip-grant-tables option.
> - Login to root user

List all the users;

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
```

Reset password;

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('[password]') WHERE User='[username]';
```

restart the MySQL Process without the --skip-grant-tables option.

Or,

There is no need to restart the MySQL server.

use `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after the update mysql.user statement for password change.

> The FLUSH statement tells the server to reload the grant tables into memory so that it notices the password change.

The `--skip-grant-options` enables anyone to connect without a password and with all privileges. Because this is insecure, you might want to

> use *--skip-grant-tables* in conjunction with *--skip-networking* to prevent remote clients from connecting.

from: reference: [resetting-permissions-generic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-generic)