# Can a root user see other users' passwords?

Tags: mysql

Can a root user decrypt the passwords of other users using Mysql? If it is, can you please explain me how it can be done? If it is not possible, if a user forgot his password, how can a root user help him?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to recover MySql user Password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251261/is-there-a-way-to-recover-mysql-user-password)

Comment: No. For details see [How can I decrypt MySql passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654819/how-can-i-decrypt-mysql-passwords)

Comment: Only if they are encrypted. They should be hashed.